# C++ template class inheritance

Tags: c++, visual-c++, templates, gcc

I have been porting some C++ code, which was written long time ago, and is normally compiled with Visual C++ (Visual Studio 7.1 version) and Intel C++ Compiler 11.0, the target platform is Linux (Suse x86-64), with GCC 4.3.2 and Intel C++ Compiler 11.1

The problem is that code like this

FileA.h

```
template<typename T, int dim>
class A
{
 public:
  A(){};
  ~A(){};
 protected:
  void foo1(){};
}
```

FileB.h

```
#include "FileA.h"
template<typename T>
class B : public A<T, 2>
{
 public:
  B(){};
  ~B(){};
  void foo(){ foo1(); }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "FileB.h"
int main()
{
 B<float> b = B<float>();
}
```

does not compile on Linux (Intel C++ 11.1, GCC 4.3.2), but perfectly compiles on Windows (Visual C++ 7.1, Intel C++ 11.0), althow it surely must not depend on platform.
GCC tells that if I change foo1() to foo1(T a) it will work (and it does), but I can not change the code, and have to use Intel C++ for final release.

I would be glad if anyone could help with any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo1` is not a dependent expression so the base class, which is a dependent type, is not used to resolve the `foo1` call.

As you can't change the code, you are stuffed. If you could change the code you would need to change the expression to be dependent. Typically this is done by changing it to `this->foo1()`.

Comment: Yes, that work, thank you. There still remains the question why that code is fine for Visual C++ and Intel C++ 11.0 on Windows?

Comment: @nexx: Visual C++ is notoriously laxist on dependant names. This is **not standard** and **not likely to change**. You can forget `typename`, or forget to explicitely qualify dependant function calls, and it will unportably work fine.

Comment: I am not surprised that Visual C++ (7.1) is out of standards, actually, but much more surprised about Intel C++, considering that the Windows version is 11.0 and Linus version is 11.1

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known problem with templates. It is explained in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.18)

Answer (score 0):

On gcc 4.4.1 (os is Ubuntu) version I could turn the compile error into a compile warning, by using the `-fpermissive` option to the compiler.

Edit: The fact that some compiler accept it, doesn't mean it will continue to accept it in future versions.

Comment: Except that it will break customer's code base if it changes. So we are stuck with the laxist behaviour of visual C++. With /W4, you get warnings though.